# return list with angular in memory web api and Observeble not Work

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I Need to Return List of Products With `Angular` and `angular in memory web api` But When i'm Using This Code it Not Show me any thing , not show Error  . When i use this code in service it show me empty array : `.do(data => console.log('get products : ' + JSON.stringify(data)))`

Product-Data :

**use this for add product in `web api`:**

```
import { Iproduct } from './iproduct';
import { InMemoryDbService, InMemoryBackendConfig } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

export class ProductData implements InMemoryDbService, InMemoryBackendConfig {

  createDb() {
    let products: Iproduct[] = [
      {
        'id': 1,
        'productName': 'Product 1',
        'productCode': '0011'
      },
      {
        'id': 2,
        'productName': 'Product 2',
        'productCode': '0023'
      },
      {
        'id': 5,
        'productName': 'Product 5',
        'productCode': '0048'
      },
      {
        'id': 8,
        'productName': 'Product 8',
        'productCode': '0022'
      },
      {
        'id': 10,
        'productName': 'Product 10',
        'productCode': '0042'
      }
    ];
    return { products };
  }
}
```

Product-Service :

use this for return List Product :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

import {Iproduct} from './iproduct';
@Injectable()
export class ProductService {

  private baseUrl = 'api/products';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getProducts(): Observable<Iproduct[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .do(data => console.log('get products : ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Product-List Component :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Iproduct} from '../iproduct';
import {ProductService} from '../product.service';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {

  pageTitle = 'Product List';
  errorMessage: string;
  products: Iproduct[];
  constructor(private productService: ProductService , private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productService.getProducts()
      .subscribe(products => this.products = products  , error => this.errorMessage = <any>error );

  }

}
```

product-List Html :

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    {{pageTitle}}
  </div>

  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="has-error" *ngIf="errorMessage">{{errorMessage}}</div>

    <div class="table-responsive">

      <table class="table" *ngIf="products && products.length">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Product</th>
          <th>Code</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let product of products">
          <td><a [routerLink]="['/products', product.id]">
            {{product.productName}}
          </a>
          </td>
          <td>{{ product.productCode}}</td>
          <td>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/products', product.id, 'edit']">
              Edit
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update :**

i change `http` to `httpclient` but it show me this error :

> ERROR in src/app/product/product.service.ts(43,34): error TS2345: Argument of type 'RequestOptions' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]:
>    string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
>     Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
>       Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
>         Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
>           Index signature is missing in type 'Headers'.
>   src/app/product/product.service.ts(50,51): error TS2345: Argument of type 'RequestOptions' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string |
>    string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
>     Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
>       Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
>         Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
>           Index signature is missing in type 'Headers'.
>   src/app/product/product.service.ts(58,44): error TS2345: Argument of type 'RequestOptions' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string |
>    string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
>     Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
>       Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
>         Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
>           Index signature is missing in type 'Headers'.

**Fix**

i change `getProducts()` to this code and using `httpClient` :

```
      getProducts (): Observable<Iproduct[]> {
    return this.http.get<Iproduct[]>(this.baseUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(data => console.log(`fetched Products`)),
        catchError(this.handleError('getProducts', []))
      );
  }
```

and Constructor :

`constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }`

Comment: Your service constructor must be like constructor(private http: **HttpClient** ) (you are using "sintax" httpClient, but using http). see https://angular.io/guide/http to known how use httpClient

Comment: @Eliseo i Update the Question . it show me that error

Comment: @Eliseo thank you man . it fixed . thnaks man